# Move single or multiple files to certain file path problem

Tags: php, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I have a problem with the upload file function. Now I cannot send the multiple or single file to my file location. I have checked it because backend (upload.php)cannot get the isset($_FILES['attachment']) data. Hope someone can guide me on how to solve it.

Below is my sample coding:

`HTML`

```html
<input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment" style="width:250px;"/>
```

`javascript`

```html
var checker = $('#attachment').val();
        if(checker != ""){
            var attachment = $('#attachment').files[0];
            formData.append('attachment', attachment);
        }
        formData.append('string','post_data');
        //console.log(formData);
        for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS (requires jQuery 1.6+)
            processData: false, // NEEDED, DON'T OMIT THIS
            // ... Other options like success and etc
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert(data.msg);
            }
        });
```

`php (upload.php)`

```html
<?PHP
$targetFolder='upload_doc/asset';
    $file_checklist = array("site_picture", "site_schematic", "site_certificate", "attachment");
    foreach($file_checklist as $file){
        echo $_POST['string'];
        
        if(isset($_FILES[$file])){
            $tempFile = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = $targetFolder;
            $file_name=time().'_' . $_FILES[$file]['name'];
            $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' .$file_name;
            if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){
                echo "done";
            } else {
                echo 'Invalid file type.';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The result, the file cannot move to `upload_doc/asset`